# Better way to check for multiple regex conditions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking for a better way to check, if a string matches multiple regex patterns (or not).
This is my approach so far:

```
class Bob
  def hey(remark)
    if remark =~ upcase && !(remark =~ downcase) && !(remark =~ numbers)
      'Whoa, chill out!'
    elsif remark =~ ends_with_questionmark
      'Sure.'
    elsif (remark =~ numbers) && (remark =~ upcase) && !(remark =~ downcase)
      'Whoa, chill out!'
    else
      'Whatever.'
    end 
  end
  def numbers
    /[\d]+/
  end
  def downcase
    /[a-z]+/
  end
  def upcase
    /[A-Z]+/
  end
  def ends_with_questionmark
    /[\?]$/
  end
end
```

Comment: This logic elsif (remark =~ numbers) && (remark =~ upcase) && !(remark =~ downcase)  will never be true. and I think it is better to define regex as constants rather than methods

Comment: @ToanNguyen, suppose `remark = 7UP`?

Comment: This question was refactored in the talk - "Overkill" by Katrina Owen. Its quite interesting to see how she improves the readability, Do review it, you may find it interesting. Perhaps have a look at how I solved it after listening to the talk: http://exercism.io/submissions/736312a54538483ea43cefdb07592e8d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it difficult to comprehend what `Bob#hey` is doing. One possibility is to define some appropriately-named helper methods in the `String` class:

```
class String
  def contains_a_digit?()            !!(self =~ /\d/)        end
  def contains_no_digits?()          !self.contains_a_digit? end
  def contains_an_uppercase_char?()  !!(self =~ /[A-Z]/)     end
  def contains_no_lowercase_chars?() self !~ /[a-z]/         end
  def ends_with_questionmark?()      !!(self =~ /[\?]$/)     end
end
```

Note that (for example) `self =~ /\d+/` and `self =~ /\d/` are here interchangeable; both return a truthy value if and only if `self` contains at least one digit. Incidentally, the receiver, `self`, must be explicit here.

Aside to readers unfamiliar with `!!`: if `truthy` is a variable holding any  value other than `false` or `nil`, `!!(truthy) => true`, `!!(nil) => false` and `!!(false) => false`. In other words, `!!` is a trick to convert truthy values to `true` and falsy values to `false` (which I've used merely to improve readability).

Let's try these methods:

```
str = 'U2d?'                     #=> "U2d?" 
str.contains_a_digit?            #=> true 
str.contains_no_digits?          #=> false 
str.contains_an_uppercase_char?  #=> true 
str.contains_no_lowercase_chars? #=> false 
str.ends_with_questionmark?      #=> true
```

With Ruby 2.1+, if one is disinclined to monkey-patch the `String` class, one can use [Refinements](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html).

Now the method `Bob#hey` can be defined in natural way:

```
class Bob
  def hey(remark)
    case
    when remark.contains_no_digits? &&
         remark.contains_an_uppercase_char? &&
         remark.contains_no_lowercase_chars?
      'Whoa, chill out! (1st)'
    when remark.ends_with_questionmark?
      'Sure.'
    when remark.contains_a_digit? &&
         remark.contains_an_uppercase_char? &&
         remark.contains_no_lowercase_chars?
      'Whoa, chill out! (2nd)'
    else
      'Whatever.'
    end
  end
end
```

Let's try it.

```
bob = Bob.new
bob.hey("I PAID IN $US!")   #=> "Whoa, chill out! (1st)" 
bob.hey("What's that?")     #=> "Sure." 
bob.hey("I FLEW ON A 777!") #=> "Whoa, chill out! (2nd)" 
bob.hey("I give up.")       #=> "Whatever."
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in general more than 2 `else`s should be a `case`:

```
def hey remark
  case
    when remark =~ upcase && !(remark =~ downcase) && !(remark =~ numbers) then 'Whoa, chill out!'
    when remark =~ ends_with_questionmark then 'Sure.'
    when (remark =~ numbers) && (remark =~ upcase) && !(remark =~ downcase) then 'Whoa, chill out!'
    else 'Whatever.'
  end
end
```

But I also think those regexes need work, they probably don't do what you think.

Also you can change `!(str =~ /re/)` to `str !~ /re/`

Comment: I'm with you on the use of `case statements`. I find I very rarely use `if...end` anymore, even when it results in a naked `case` with no `elsif`. I just find `case statements` easier to read and aesthetically more pleasing to the eye. About the only time I use `if` is `do something if...`.

Answer (score 0):

You code can be rewritten like this

```
def hey(remark)
    if remark =~  /[A-Z]+/
      'Whoa, chill out!'
    elsif remark =~  /[\?]$/
      'Sure.'
    else
      'Whatever.'
    end 
  end
```